# "Couldn't contact the RemoteTestNG client" error when trying to run tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

### Issue

Working with TestNG on a maven managed project, i can't seem to run tests via the TestNG eclipse plugin. When trying to run tests, the following error message pops up (inside a dialog window):

> Couldn't contact the RemoteTestNG client. Make sure you don't have an
>   older version of testng.jar on your class path.
>
> Reason:
>   Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG.

How to resolve this?

### Things I have tried

(After asking **all** my peers at the office QA department on this, and looking up information via the common search engines and on TestNG forums)

- Making sure I don't have an older version on my class path (naturally).
- Eliminating possible collisions between maven imported jars and jars used by the TestNG eclipse plugin (both are of version 6.7, and the project's `pom.xml` confirmed to use only its own dependent jar).
- Performing maven update and build after said changes.
- Running on a different JRE (specifically 1.7.0).

### Relevant information

#### Environment:

- **OS:** Win XP pro SP3
- **JRE:** 1.6.0 update 31
- **TestNG:** 6.7
- **Maven:** 3.0.3
- **IDE:** Eclipse Juno Java EE SR1

#### `pom.xml` content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>SGTest</artifactId>
    <name>SGTest</name>
    <description>Service Grid Test project for XAP</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my_product.quality.sgtest</groupId>
        <artifactId>SGTest-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/my_product/quality/sgtest/SGTest-parent/3.0.0/SGTest-parent-3.0.0.pom</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <xap.home>${env.XAP_LATEST}</xap.home>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_product</groupId>
            <artifactId>my_opensource_product</artifactId>
            <version>${gsVersion}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${xap.home}/lib/required/my_opensource_product.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_product</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${gsVersion}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${xap.home}/lib/required/gs-runtime.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_product.quality</groupId>
            <artifactId>DashboardReporter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>apps</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_product.quality</groupId>
            <artifactId>webuitf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_product.quality</groupId>
            <artifactId>wanem</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my_opensource_product.xenserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>xenserver-machine-provisioning</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swift.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence-soap</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hyperic</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${xap.home}/lib/platform/sigar/sigar.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        <classpathDependencyExcludes>com.my_product.quality.sgtest.apps.security:processor</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        <classpathDependencyExcludes>com.my_product.quality.sgtest.apps.archives:customSecurityProcessor</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        <classpathDependencyScopeExclude>runtime</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>
                    </classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${includes}</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>${excludes}</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <reportsDirectory>${sgtest.summary.dir}</reportsDirectory>
                    <reportFormat>xml</reportFormat>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>configfailurepolicy</name>
                            <value>continue</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>suitename</name>
                            <value>${sgtest.suiteName}${sgtest.suiteId}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>testname</name>
                            <value>${sgtest.suiteName}${sgtest.suiteId}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>outputDir</name>
                            <value>${sgtest.summary.dir}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>framework.testng.SGTestNGListener,framework.testng.SGTestNgSuiteSplitter,framework.testng.report.TestNgReporterImpl</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <sgtest.suiteId>${sgtest.suiteId}</sgtest.suiteId>
                        <sgtest.numOfSuites>${sgtest.numOfSuites}</sgtest.numOfSuites>
                        <selenium.browser>${selenium.browser}</selenium.browser>
                        <org.apache.commons.logging.Log>org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger</org.apache.commons.logging.Log>
                        <com.gs.logging.level.config>true</com.gs.logging.level.config>
                        <java.util.logging.config.file>${basedir}/logging/sgtest_logging.properties</java.util.logging.config.file>
                        <sgtest.buildFolder>${sgtest.buildFolder}</sgtest.buildFolder>
                        <sgtest.url>http://192.168.9.121:8087/sgtest3.0-xap/</sgtest.url>
                        <sgtest.disconnect.machines>${sgtest.disconnect.machines}</sgtest.disconnect.machines>
                        <com.gs.work>${com.gs.work}</com.gs.work>
                        <com.gs.deploy>${com.gs.deploy}"</com.gs.deploy>
                        <cppOS>${cppOS}</cppOS>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <detail>true</detail>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the pom of your project?

Comment: Can you try this again from a clean Eclipse workspace?

Comment: sure, @CedricBeust, i'll try this and will update on my findings tomorrow.

Comment: Are you using testng-6.0.1.jar. Please update and check once again.

Comment: Why have you changed the test folder into src/main/java instead using the conventions?

Comment: @RanjithJ, I am not using 6.0.1, please read the question.

Comment: @khmarbaise - how is this relevant?

Comment: Isn't that possible your firewall blocks the connection of the test runner?

Comment: @rlegendi - nop. firewall deactivated.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue originates from a problem which occurs when running long Java classpaths on Windows (these exceed the *process creation command limit*). It had been [reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327193) on the Eclipse bug tracking system, and was also discussed [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-msdos-windows).

To work around this on Eclipse Juno releases, we can either bypass the command limit (using the solutions suggested in the above [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-msdos-windows)), or apply the patch from the reported bug.

[Ivan Sim](https://coderwall.com/ivanhcsim) posted the patching instructions [on his coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/795oma), but I'll include an excerpt for the sake of completeness:

> 1. Download bug3271933.4.2hack.zip from the above [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327193)
> 2. Back up existing eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.4.*.jar
> 3. Copy and paste classes in the patch to org/eclipse/jdt/internal/launching in your org.eclipse.jdt.launching
>      JAR (replace existing files)
> 4. Edit the META-INF /MANIFEST.MF file in your org.eclipse.jdt.launching JAR file by removing everything starting
>      from the first "NAME:" entry. Make sure you leave two (2) line break
>      characters at the end of the file.
> 5. Re-start eclipse

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make the exact problem occur by configuring my TestNG launch configuration (within eclipse) incorrectly.
Specifically I specified for it to pass the following as a JVM argument:

```
-runTestAsTool=true
```

instead of

```
-DrunTestAsTool=true
```

Adding the missing `D` fixed it for me.
So maybe double-check how your launch configuration is configured.

Comment: my configuration is fine, see the accepted answer on what was causing this (in my case). +1, it might help others with the same symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the Sock5 proxy on your Mac OS or Windows is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

It seems TestNG tries to connect to JVM instance via creating socket to 'localhost' and in my /etc/hosts (I use linux) file I renamed localhost to something else so it bombed.

Changed back to localhost and all is good.

Comment: i don't see how this has anything to do with the question

Comment: generally speaking, removing the 127.0.0.1 localhost entry in hosts on linux is going to cause massive problems for everything in linux.