# Neo4j No query engine installed

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I tried running the Neo4j sample program JavaQuery.java.  I used the neo4j maven script provided to get all the dependencies.  However when I run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No query engine installed.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.noQueryEngine(NoQueryEngine.java:56)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.executeQuery(NoQueryEngine.java:33)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:953)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:944)
    at JavaQuery.JavaQuery.run(JavaQuery.java:60)
    at JavaQuery.JavaQuery.main(JavaQuery.java:44)
```

I haven't found any documentation about how to get the query engine installed.

the simple low level java interface seems to work, but I haven't been able to get Cypher queries to work.

How do I get past this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need neo4j cypher dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I put this, I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722863/org-neo4j-kernel-graphdatabasequeryservice-no-dependecy-satisfies-interface

Answer (score 3):

The `neo4j-cypher` dependency that @shazin mentioned, should come along when you depend on:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, gentlemen.  I'm using netbeans as my IDE.  It does show the neo4j-cyper-2.2.0.jar in the dependencies list with a location of  /home/tmk49/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.2.0/neo4j-cypher-2.2.0.jar. Are there other places that I might look? Thank you.

Comment: I put this, I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722863/org-neo4j-kernel-graphdatabasequeryservice-no-dependecy-satisfies-interface

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I had the dependency `org.neo4j:neo4j:*` configured. Here are some ideas.

### Cause #1 : Dependency shadowing

It could be one of your dependencies conflicting with transitive dependency from neo4j. Putting neo4j higher in your SBT could solve this issue.
(This was what worked for me)

### Cause #2 : Maximum command line reach (Windows only)

Neo4j has tons of jars. It could be the `java` command that is too long for windows' maximum number of characters. See: [How to set a long Java classpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-windows)