# org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDatabaseQueryService No dependency satisfies interface

Tags: java, neo4j, gtfs, neo4j-spatial

I am just writing a simple program where I am uploading my GTFS files to Neo4j Spatial.

I believe it's some configuration error or some problem with Neo4j-spatial libraries, which is why I am not uploading my code which is quite basic as specified [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial):

I imported all the required libraries of neo4j:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <version>0.25.4-neo4j-3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Despite adding all of these neo4j libraries I was getting the error that query engine not found so I decided to add the following too:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But now I get a very strange error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDatabaseQueryService
```

Complete Error when one looks at it

```
main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Agency
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.ShapePoint
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Route
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Stop
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Trip
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.StopTime
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.ServiceCalendar
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.ServiceCalendarDate
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.FareAttribute
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.FareRule
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Frequency
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Pathway
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Transfer
 main INFO  serialization.GtfsReader - reading entities: org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.FeedInfo
 Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDatabaseQueryService
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.DependencyResolver$Adapter.resolveDependency(DependencyResolver.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.queryService(ClassicCoreSPI.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.function.Suppliers$1.get(Suppliers.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.lambda$create$0(Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.newContext(Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.newContext(Neo4jTransactionalContextFactory.java:38)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:429)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:413)
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.utilities.ReferenceNodes.getReferenceNode(ReferenceNodes.java:32)
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.getSpatialRoot(SpatialDatabaseService.java:77)
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.getLayer(SpatialDatabaseService.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.containsLayer(SpatialDatabaseService.java:277)
    at integrations.GTFS2Neo4jImporter.execute(GTFS2Neo4jImporter.java:50)
    at api.AdminApi.uploadGTFSFRorRegion(AdminApi.java:38)
    at api.AdminApi.main(AdminApi.java:47)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.