# Long Java classpath solution

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to figure out a way of going around the problem of a long classpath in windows. Although I am in Linux (that is why the examples bellow are on a unix format), the end users may be in linux and I know the problem happens.

My application download and create a string of the jars and files it needs to run. It than generates a string such as:

```
java -classpath path_to_file1:path_to_file2:path_to_file3 jvm_args MainClass
```

And runs the application. This works fine in Linux but it explodes in windows because the classpath is too long.

The problem I understood and I have tried the solution proposed on: [How to set a long Java classpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-windows)

However I had no success since the path to the MainClass is not found (it is on the classpath!). Here is what I did:

I have the following folder structure:

```
[root]
├── classes
│   └── com
│       └── tst
│           ├── CPTest1.class
│           ├── CPTest2.class
│           └── CPTest3.class
└── com
    └── tst
        ├── CPTest1.java
        ├── CPTest2.java
        └── CPTest3.java
```

the classes were compiled by calling:

```
javac -d classes -cp . com/tst/*
```

And here are the files:

**CPTest1.java**

```
package com.tst;

public class CPTest1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Run CPTest1.main()");
    }
}
```

**CPTest2.java**

```
package com.tst;

public class CPTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Run CPTest2.main()");
        CPTest1 cpt1 = new CPTest1();
    }
}
```

**CPTest3.java**

```
package com.tst;

public class CPTest3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Run CPTest3.main()");
        CPTest1 cpt1 = new CPTest1();
        CPTest2 cpt2 = new CPTest2();
    }
}
```

Now if I am on **[root]** and run:

```
java -cp classes com.tst.CPTest3
```

I see the correct output.
However if I first generate the "pathing jar" as the solution I pointed out suggests, by creating a file:
**cpTest.txt** (I've tried this with relative and full path)

```
Class-Path: classes
```

and create the jar using:

```
jar -cvfm cp.jar cpTest.txt
```

than finally trying to run:

```
java -cp cp.jar com.tst.CPTest3
```

all I get is an error of not finding the CPTest3 class:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tst.CPTest3
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that com.tst.CPTest3 is in the cp.jar? You can easily check that by unzipping the jar. Look also at maybe using a manifest file if you need many jars on the classpath: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: does this only work with jars? The jar I created does not contain anything other than the Manifest file with the class-path entry. I understood that was the idea behind the answer on the post I mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a long Java classpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-windows)

Comment: As you've might have seen I have mentioned this issue in the description. So it is not a duplicate, but an attempt of solution which I didn't understand the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Use `java -jar` and put all the dependent JAR files into the main JAR file's Class-path manifest entry.

Comment: well that is what I did by creating the "pathing jar" wasn't it? I mean in my example I am not using other jars, but just classes... I wanted to try this since in my actual project I have JAR's as well as Manifests, images and so on and so forth