# neo4j embedded: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No query engine installed

Tags: neo4j

I am getting the following exception, when I try to execute the query against embedded Neo4J instance:

```
No query engine installed.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No query engine installed.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.noQueryEngine(NoQueryEngine.java:56)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.executeQuery(NoQueryEngine.java:33)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.executeQuery(ClassicCoreSPI.java:77)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:429)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:412)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:396)
```

The following dependency is included: "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-cypher" % "3.1.3"

This is my code snippet, which I execute from my test:

```
val graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(my_db_path))
graphDb.execute(my_query)
```

And this is my dependency tree for Neo4J part:

```
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
...
[info]   |     
[info]   +-org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.4.3
[info]   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:3.1.3 [S]
[info]   | +-net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-codegen:3.1.3
[info]   | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:2.3.9
[info]   | | +-com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3:2.3.9
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3 [S]
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3 [S]
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0:3.0.8
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.0:3.0.8
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | | |   
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:3.1.3
[info]   | | +-com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.3.3
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1:3.1.3
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | | |   
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:3.1.3
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | 
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |     
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:3.1.3
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | 
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |     
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:3.1.3
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.5.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:5.5.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   | 
[info]   | |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |   |   
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:3.1.3
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | | 
[info]   | |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   | |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   | |     
[info]   | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3 [S]
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:3.1.3
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.5.0
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:5.5.0
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:3.1.3
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-io:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]   |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   | +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   | 
[info]   |   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:3.1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.5.0
[info]   |   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:3.1.3
[info]   |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-common:3.1.3
[info]   |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:3.1.3
[info]   |     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:3.1.3
[info]   |     
[info]   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.23
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.23 (evicted by: 1.7.25)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
[info]   | 
[info]   +-team.supernova.hubble:hubble-messages_2.12:0.15-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info]     +-com.google.guava:guava:19.0
[info]     +-com.trueaccord.scalapb:scalapb-runtime_2.12:0.5.47 [S]
[info]     | +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0
[info]     | +-com.lihaoyi:fastparse_2.12:0.4.2 [S]
[info]     | | +-com.lihaoyi:fastparse-utils_2.12:0.4.2 [S]
[info]     | | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.12:0.1.3 [S]
[info]     | | | 
[info]     | | +-com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.12:0.1.3 [S]
[info]     | | 
[info]     | +-com.trueaccord.lenses:lenses_2.12:0.4.9 [S]
[info]     | 
[info]     +-com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.12:2.6.1 [S]
[info]     | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9
[info]     | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 (evicted by: 2.8.9)
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | | 
[info]     | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.9
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 (evicted by: 2.8.9)
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | |   
[info]     | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 (evicted by: 2.8.9)
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.9
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 (evicted by: 2.8.9)
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9
[info]     | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9
[info]     | |   
[info]     | +-com.typesafe.play:play-functional_2.12:2.6.1 [S]
[info]     | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
[info]     | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.3 [S]
[info]     | +-org.typelevel:macro-compat_2.12:1.1.1 [S]
[info]     | 
[info]     +-org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.11.0.0
[info]     | +-net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.3.0
[info]     | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
[info]     | +-org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.2.6
[info]     | 
[info]     +-org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.23
[info]       +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.23 (evicted by: 1.7.25)
[info]       +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
[info]       
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 4, 2017 3:25:38 PM
```

Does anyone has any clue, what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your pom.xml, please.

Comment: It is an SBT, actually, but these are the URLs:
build.sbt - https://github.com/Supernova-Team/hubble/blob/features/hubble-graphite-writer/build.sbt
dependencies: https://github.com/Supernova-Team/hubble/blob/features/hubble-graphite-writer/project/Dependencies.scala

and it fails for the following project - hubbleGraphiteReaderDependencies

Answer (score 0):

## Verify proper classpath at runtime

In order to load cypher engine, you need few jars name "neo4j-cypher-compiler*.jar". Evaluate `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` in debug mode to see the completed list of jars access by the JVM. It looks like you have those based on your SBT output but runtime is the only truth.

### Cause #1 : Dependency shadowing

It could be one of your dependencies conflicting with transitive dependency from neo4j. Putting neo4j higher in your SBT could solve this issue.
(This was what worked for me)

### Cause #2 : Maximum command line reach (Windows only)

Neo4j has tons of jars. It could be the `java` command that is too long for windows' maximum number of characters. See: [How to set a long Java classpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-windows)